# Nuget package created by VS does not update version

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a nuget package `<name>.1.0.1.nupkg` generated by a build in Visual studio. After some changes to the source code, I want to generate a new version.

On the project `properties` I change the `Package version` under `Package` to `1.0.2` and make sure to save.

When building the project, the package is created with the name `<name>.1.0.1.nupkg`.

*Successfully created package `'<Path>\<name>.1.0.1.nupkg'`*

I have tried restarting Visual Studio. Are there additional configurations needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for additional configurations. It should work, did you right-click your project node > choose Pack to generate the package?

If this doesn't work, you can try to set the `version` in `proj` file. Right-click your project > Unload Project > right-click it again > Edit Project File > add following codes

```
<Version>1.0.2</Version>
```

in the `<PropetyGroup></PropertyGroup>` like this

```
<PropetyGroup>
    <Version>1.0.2</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and then right-click your project > Reload Project > Rebuild your project > right-click the project > Pack.

Some **other suggestions**:

Try to clear the cache such as `.vs`, `bin`, `obj` folders in your project folder. Rebuild your project.

=================================

**Update:**

Based on @Haukland's final solution, switch to use `PackageVersion` instead of `Version`.

Comment: I ended up manually updating the csproj as you suggest, however `PackageVersion` and not Version

Comment: Ok, good to know.